# Create XAML Splash page and navigate to Tabbed page

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, mvvm-light, splash-screen

I have pretty much set up my XF application using MVVMLight and following [this article](https://github.com/JoeM-RP/bootstrap-mvvmlight).

I would now like to introduce a XAML Splash page, have it loaded at startup by assigning it to the MainPage property in App.xaml.cs. Once loaded, in the splash page, I would like to do some asynchronous tasks to initialize the app i.e. fetch initial data from an API etc. Once this is done, I would like to navigate to the MainTabbed page.

I haven't written the initialization logic as yet so I'm using Thread.Sleep to simulate this.

I have read a lot of articles and tried a couple of things and I'm stuck at a point where I have either one of these issues:

1. Splash page loads but then does not navigate to the Tabbed page.
2. Splash page does not load at all and navigates to Tabbed page
   directly.

[This article](http://blog.masterdevs.com/xf-day-9/) is the closest that I have come across but I seem to be getting an error while releasing the semaphore:

```
05-09 19:22:12.471 I/MonoDroid(14342): System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Threading.SemaphoreFullException: Adding the specified count to the semaphore would cause it to exceed its maximum count.
05-09 19:22:12.471 I/MonoDroid(14342):   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Release (System.Int32 releaseCount) [0x0004c] in <fcbf47a04b2e4d90beafbae627e1fca4>:0 
05-09 19:22:12.471 I/MonoDroid(14342):   at System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Release () [0x00000] in <fcbf47a04b2e4d90beafbae627e1fca4>:0
```

Appreciate any advice on the above or how one could implement a splash page using xaml (if that even makes sense conceptually) as most of the articles are using native implementations or images in the native projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok!! So I figured out the navigation and did not need to bother about the semaphore either.

The following steps detail out the answer:

1. Create the long-running method in a service class or a separate class as follows

   ```
   public async Task LongRunning()
   {
       //Write code to download data from an API or something.
   }
   ```
2. Create a 'SplashPage.xaml' file and assign it to the MainPage property in App.cs. This will set the SplashPage as the 1st or root page in the NavigationStack.
3. If MVVMLight is being used as per the [link](https://github.com/JoeM-RP/bootstrap-mvvmlight) then:

   a. Create a SplashViewModel.cs file.

   b. In SplashViewModel.cs, create a private async void method called Initialize that has the following code:

   ```
   private async void Initialize()
   {
       //Need to await till the task is done. Very important
       await yourService.LongRunning();

       //Only after task is done should it navigate to next page
       NavigationService.NavigateTo(nameof(MainTabbedPage));
   }
   ```
4. After navigating to the MainTabbedPage, the MainTabbedPage will become the 2nd page in the navigation stack. This should not be the case as the 1st or root page should always be MainTabbedPage. Moreover, it is not required to navigate to the SplashPage again. In order to fix this, place the below code in the OnAppearing event of the MainTabbedPage.

   ```
   protected override void OnAppearing()
   {
       base.OnAppearing();
       var splashPage = Navigation.NavigationStack[0];
       Navigation.RemovePage(splashPage);
   }
   ```

   This will remove the SplashPage from the navigation stack and set the MainTabbedPage as the root page before navigating to any other pages.
5. If you do not use MVVMLight but write code directly in the code-behind or something then the code in step 3b can be placed in the code-behind - SplashPage.xaml.cs and the Initialize method can be called in the constructor.

I spent quite some time figuring this out so I hope this helps when needed.